# Is is possible to do a Softphone on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, sip

I'm interested in development of a softphone for Windows Phone 8.1 (or maybe Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 which is less desirable because it's not cross-platform). But till now I see that it will be very limited.

1. When you remove an application from foreground it stops working. Seems to me you can't handle communications ( audio e.t.c. ) in background task. Cause background tasks are trigger based actually.

Ok, we have an example of Linphone which sends audio in background but Linphone is Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1, not Windows Phone 8.1.

2. You can't have a background task handling SIP communications while your application is not working. Linphone doesn't respond to incoming call if it's not in foreground. So seems it's not even possible in Silverlight.

Ok, I can have Push notifications for incoming calls which will launch my application. But Push is not always a desirable choice.

What do you think of it? Are there any solutions or workarounds which i missed?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking, but have you seen [this, on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The article you gave me "Applies to: Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 only". If you read carefully the title you will see that I'm asking about "Windows Phone 8.1" which is completely different platform and has a huge advantage to use same UI on Desktop and Phone. So thanks for downvoting anyway :-)

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted; but you do say, in your first paragraph "or maybe Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1", which is *exactly* what that article is about.

Comment: Ok, I added clarification about Silverlight 8.1. But dont understand the reason of downvotes. I have two technical troubles and don't know if there's a way to implement what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486.aspx) VoIP is a "Windows Phone 8 feature for which there is no Windows Phone Store equivalent". Currently, you would need to implement separate clients for Phone ([using the Silverlight approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) and Windows Store.

It would still be possible to link the apps, and have them *show* as a Universal App in the store, and you could still use Portable Class Libraries to share your application logic between platforms